# C# VSTO: Highlighting E-mail Body Text - ClearHitHighlight() not clearing?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, highlight

Using VSTO and C#, I'm trying to get Outlook to highlight specific words in an e-mail body.  So far I've been able to get this done using the code below:

```
       Outlook.MailItem mailItem = this.inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;

       if (inspector.IsWordMail())
       {
           var outlookWordDocument = inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
           if (outlookWordDocument == null || outlookWordDocument.Application.Selection == null)
           { return; }

           var wordRange = outlookWordDocument.Application.Selection.Range;

           Word.Find find_highlight = wordRange.Find;
           find_highlight.HitHighlight("apples", Word.WdColor.wdColorDarkRed);
           find_highlight.ClearHitHighlight(); // trying to clear for testing purposes, but does nothing
       }
```

My problem is that the ClearHitHighlight() function isn't clearing anything.  The only way I can clear is if I perform another search right after.  See comments below:

```
find_highlight.HitHighlight("apples"); //highlights "apples"
find_highlight.HitHighlight("oranges"); //highlights "oranges" too
find_highlight.ClearHitHighlight(); //does nothing
find_highlight.HitHighlight("pears"); //clears previous highlights, adds pears
```

As an alternative I could highlight the text by formatting the actual body of the e-mail, but this HitHighlight function seems to be more appropriate - if only I could figure out how to clear the markings when finished!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling find on the Word Range, call find on the document's content variable.  Not sure exactly why, but this change causes the correct behaviour.

Change this:

```
var wordRange = outlookWordDocument.Application.Selection.Range;

Word.Find find_highlight = wordRange.Find;
```

To this:

```
Word.Find find_highlight = outlookWordDocument.Content.Find;
```